# Nvidia drivers update

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have downloaded that latest Nvidia drivers for my system. They are in the downloads folder, all I do is drag it into terminal.

When I am root user it checks the integrity and runs checks on it.

When it starts to unpack I get splash screen telling me the following:

> You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before
>    installing.  For further details, please see the section 
>    INSTALLING THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver
>    download page at www.nvidia.com.

How do I exit X server? Is there a command I can run?

And once I exit should it update my drivers normally?

Would it have an effect if I change the propriety drivers to Nvidia?

Comment: Tip: sudo lightdm stop if you use Unity

Comment: Why do you try to install drivers this way? It is not a good idea. You can install latest drivers from ppa.

Comment: @Pilot6 sorry about the second reject - is was just a mis-click, thankfully  a moderator stepped in :-)

Answer (score 1):

Much better way to install latest drivers for nvidia is to do it from ppa. In this case they will stay after kernel updates. Just run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

And you install the same driver a correct way.